# A certain sum of three variables

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $0 < \gamma < 1.$
I have this sum 
$$
S(n) = \sum_{\stackrel{n = x_1+x_2+x_3, \ x_i > 0} {  x_i \not = x_j}} 
\frac{1}{x_1^{\gamma} x_2^{\gamma} x_3^{\gamma}}.
$$
I was curious to find what this sum equals to (or
a good lower and upper bound) as $n$ becomes large.
Could someone tell me how to approach (or answer to) such a problem?
Thanks!